# see how many times the sum of 2 die are equal to 24 python

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I'm creating a code in which two "special" die roll a sum of 24.

```
def is24():

    die1 = [ i for i in range(20)]
    die2 = [ i for i in range(21) if i is not 9]

    d1 = random.randrange(len(die1))
    d2 = random.randrange(len(die2))
```

I am confused on what to put on the first line of the code below as I keep getting an error

```
    if d1 + d2 == 24: return 1



trials = 100000
random.seed(15)
s = 0
for i in range(trials):
    s += is24()

print("The estimate of the probability is")
print(s/trials)
```

Comment: what is your error? better yet, do you know what happens if  `d1 + d2 != 24`

Comment: After you've fixed your function per @pylang's answer your program will run but it won't give the correct answer.  To get the correct answer you'll want to use `random.choice`, not `random.randrange`.

Comment: Automatic -1 for "an error". [Edit] to retrieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is likely related to adding an `int` to a `None`.  This is because functions return `None` by default, which occur whenever your `if` statement fails.  Try this:

```
import random


def is24():
    """Return 1 if the target is met."""
    die1 = [ i for i in range(20)]
    die2 = [ i for i in range(21) if i is not 9]

    d1 = random.randrange(len(die1))
    d2 = random.randrange(len(die2))

    if d1 + d2 == 24: 
        return 1
    return 0                                   # include this


trials = 100000
random.seed(15)
s = 0
for i in range(trials):
    s += is24()
s
# 3798
```

Now `0` is returned when the `if` statement fails, which does not contribute to the sum `s`.

Comment: Add why OP should include the `return 0` line

Comment: Thanks, idk why I forgot an else statement

Comment: Yes, an `else` block can also work.   Here `return 0` is a "default `else`" block.  This is, when the `if` statement fails, there is no other option than to return `None` unless specified otherwise.